# how to send message to whatsapp number programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to send message(text,image,videos) to whatsapp from C# Asp.net Application.

Comment: This will help you, WhatsAPINet - https://github.com/perezdidac/WhatsAPINet

Comment: are you struggling with a specific problem or just on a spree for a library?

Comment: the project github.com is no longer exist bro @andrey.shedko

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i find perfect solution on [This Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4i4G7GBSgnI&t=7m00s).

Following code (C#) I used for sending message-

```
//Send ( button_click )
        string from = "9199********";
        string to = txtTo.Text;//Sender Mobile
        string msg = txtMessage.Text;

        WhatsApp wa = new WhatsApp(from, "BnXk*******B0=", "NickName", true, true);

        wa.OnConnectSuccess += () =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connected to whatsapp...");

            wa.OnLoginSuccess += (phoneNumber, data) =>
            {
                wa.SendMessage(to, msg);
                MessageBox.Show("Message Sent...");
            };

            wa.OnLoginFailed += (data) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Failed : {0}", data); 
            };

            wa.Login();
        };

        wa.OnConnectFailed += (ex) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed...");
        };

        wa.Connect();
```

Comment: whatsapp doesn't provide any public api. Is it legal to do it using this code?

Comment: @RKSharma No it isn't, now exists a whatsapp business api service

Answer (score 4):

Sending bulk messages programmatically through WhatsApp is definitively against their Terms of Service, and even the author of the (third-party) API posted by andrey.shedko doesn't maintain it or accept any responsibility for it. There's a function within the app to send as many messages as you want to the people you actually know - use that instead.

Within their [Legal](http://www.whatsapp.com/legal/) section:

`(iii) you will not attempt to reverse engineer, alter or modify any part of the Service`

and

`C. You agree not to use or launch any automated system, including without limitation, "robots," "spiders," "offline readers," etc. or "load testers" such as wget, apache bench, mswebstress, httpload, blitz, Xcode Automator, Android Monkey, etc., that accesses the Service in a manner that sends more request messages to the WhatsApp servers in a given period of time than a human can reasonably produce in the same period by using a WhatsApp application`

They do not provide a public API, so there's no wiggle room here.

Comment: I think you missed one important thing in the article c. which says "that accesses the Service in a manner that sends more request messages to the WhatsApp servers in a given period of time than a human can reasonably produce in the same period by using a WhatsApp application" . They dont say you cannot use any API to send the message they say you canno send message more frequent than a human can do. And the question does not ask for sending Bulk message just sending message.